# Game Center Integration Errors

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to integrate GameCenter into my iPhone app.  What I am trying to do is upload the NSString highScore to my Game Center leaderboard.  I am getting issues about string compatibility, and I am not sure what to do from here.  Here is the void I call when I want to upload the highScore NSString to GameCenter

```
-(void)submitScore {
int x = [highScore floatValue];
score=&x;
GKScore *myScoreValue = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"grumpyEscapeHighScoresLeaderboard"];
myScoreValue.value = score;

[myScoreValue reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
    if(error != nil){
        NSLog(@"Score Submission Failed");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Score Submitted");
    }

}];
}
```

When it submits, I get a huge number in GameCenter (803,089,816) even though the value of the highScore NSString is 6.  Here is the error message:

```
Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int64_t' (aka 'long long') from 'int*'
```

In my ViewController.h here is what I define score as

```
int *score;
```

I am extremely new to Objective C, and coding in general.  Sorry if this question seems silly to others. I have tried researching for so long how to do this, and could not find any answers.  [Here](http://vivianaranha.com/integrating-apple-gamecenter-to-your-application/) is the tutorial where I got the code from, and modified it for my own project.

Comment: Side note - If you call `floatValue`, you should assign the result to a variable of type `float`, not `int`. If you want to assign to an `int`, then call `intValue` instead of `floatValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no reason to be using an `int *` rather than an `int` for your score value here, and similarly no reason to be storing it into your `score` instance variable if you’re only using it in the `-submitScore` method.

```
- (void)submitScore {
    GKScore *myScoreValue = [[GKScore alloc] initWithCategory:@"grumpyEscapeHighScoresLeaderboard"];
    myScoreValue.value = [highScore integerValue];

    [myScoreValue reportScoreWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
        if(error != nil){
            NSLog(@"Score Submission Failed");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Score Submitted");
        }

    }];
}
```